# Trouble escaping dollar sign in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I'm getting a bunch of text from an outside source, saving it in a variable, and then displaying that variable as part of a larger block of HTML. I need to display it as is, and dollar signs are giving me trouble.

Here's the setup:

```
# get the incoming text
my $inputText = "This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.";

print <<"OUTPUT";
before-regex: $inputText
OUTPUT

# this regex seems to have no effect
$inputText =~ s/\$/\$/g;

print <<"OUTPUT";
after-regex:  $inputText
OUTPUT
```

In real life, those `print` blocks are much larger chunks of HTML with variables inserted directly.

I tried escaping the dollar signs using `s/\$/\$/g` because my understanding is that the first `\$` escapes the regex so it searches for `$`, and the second `\$` is what gets inserted and later escapes the Perl so that it just displays `$`. But I can't get it to work.

Here's what I'm getting:

```
before-regex: This is a 0, as in . It is not a 0.
after-regex:  This is a 0, as in . It is not a 0.
```

And here's what I want to see:

```
before-regex: This is a 0, as in . It is not a 0.
after-regex:  This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.
```

Googling brings me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9716443/324625). When I try using the array and for loop in the answer, it has no effect.

How can I get the block output to display the variable exactly as it is?

Comment: I suppose that Perl works like PHP here and does the replacement of variables the moment you create the string. So there is never a `$` character in the actual string, if you don't escape it on string creation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you construct a string with double-quotes, the variable substitution happens immediately.  Your string will never contain the `$` character in that case.  If you want the `$` to appear in the string, either use single-quotes or escape it, and be aware that you will not get *any* variable substitution if you do that.

As for your regex, that is odd.  It is looking for `$` and replacing them with `$`.  If you want backslashes, you have to escape those too.

Comment: You're right, the double quotes meant it never contained the `$` so no regex would work. I'm familiar with the difference between single and double quotes, but somehow it never occurred to me when it was part of the source string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> And here's what I want to see:
>
> ```
> before-regex: This is a 0, as in . It is not a 0.
> after-regex:  This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.
> ```

hum, well, I'm not sure what the general case is, but maybe the following will do:

```
s/0/\$-/;
s/in \K/\$100/;
```

Or did you mean to start with

```
 my $inputText = "This is a \$-, as in \$100. It is not a 0.";
 # Produces the string: This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.
```

or

```
 my $inputText = 'This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.';
 # Produces the string: This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.
```

Comment: Also, using `single quotes` for your strings do not interpolate the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is using double quotes instead of single quotes in the declaration of your variable.

This should be :

```
# get the incoming text
my $inputText = 'This is a $-, as in $100. It is not a 0.';
```

Learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

This is for shell, but it's the same in Perl.