# Why does my Perl one-liner containing an escaped $ not work inside Bash backticks?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'm trying search for a `$` in a text document using a Perl one-liner in a Bash script.  I suspect it is treating the `$` as a variable.

This is my code:

```
ITEMVALUE=`perl -ne 'print /\$.*/g' file.txt`
```

The text looks something like this:

```
a bunch of random text
$80
a bunch of random text
```

I want to extract the `$80` only.  Why isn't this working, and how do I retrieve the desired text?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716443/how-to-escape-dollar-sign-in-a-string-using-perl-regex) answer, maybe it helps.

Comment: Replace backslash by two backslashes.

Comment: The Perl looks fine -- cab we see your entire Bash script, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **Command Substitution**
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name. There are two forms:
>
> ```
> $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> `command`
> ```
>
> ...
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning *except when followed by* `$`, `` ` ``, or `\` ... When using the `$(command)` form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

(emphasis added)

Bash is treating the `\` in `\$` as an escape sequence, so

```
ITEMVALUE=`perl -ne 'print /\$.*/g' file.txt`
```

actually runs

```
perl -ne 'print /$.*/g' file.txt
```

[`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) is a Perl built-in variable representing the current line number, so the regex becomes `/1*/` for the first line, `/2*/` for the second line, and so on. You'll get output for any line containing its own line number.

You can see this using Perl's [`re` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27debug%27-mode):

```
$ ITEMVALUE=`perl -Mre=debug -ne 'print /\$.*/g' file.txt`
Compiling REx "1*"
...
Compiling REx "2*"
...
```

---

To fix, use the `$(command)` form of command substitution, which is generally preferred anyway:

```
ITEMVALUE=$(perl -ne 'print /\$.*/g' file.txt)
```

Comment: Side note: using `/g` is strange since `\$.*` can only match once per line, so I would prefer `print $1 if /(\$.*)/`

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than that - that doesn't do what you think it does.

You probably want:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if m/(\$\d+)/'
```

Which matches the regex, catches the value, and prints the value. (note - will match multiple times potentially).

Comment: perhaps allow it to catch a cents value as well if it's present?

Comment: Also, that throws a warning: `Possible unintended interpolation of $\ in regex at -e line 1.`

Comment: `echo -e 'foo\n$80\nbar' | perl -ne 'print /\$.*/g'` (OP's version) prints `$80`, the same as yours. Why do you say "that doesn't do what you think it does"?

Comment: Your option worked, I found an alternative to my solution.  Use ITEMVALUE=$(command) to set variable.

Comment: This solution has one backquote and one regular quote?