# Becs character set regex

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a project where i have to validate the BECS characters. Bulk Electronic Clearing System (BECS) only allowed the following characters.

**BECS Character set**

```
Type                        Description
Numeric                     0 to 9
Alphabetic                  Uppercase A to Z and Lowercase a to z
+                           Plus sign
-                           Minus sign or hyphen
@                           At sign
SP                          Blank space
$                           Dollar sign
!                           Exclamation mark
%                           Percentage sign
&                           Ampersand
(                           Left Parenthesis
)                           Right Parenthesis
*                           Asterik
.                           Period or decimal point
/                           Solidus (slash)
#                           Number Sign (Pound or Hash)
=                           Equal Sign
:                           Colon
;                           Semicolon
?                           Question mark
,                           Comma
’                           Apostrophe
[                           Left square bracket
]                           Right square bracket
_                           Low line (underscore)
^                           Circumflex
```

I have tried the following but not working:

`preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9^_[]',?;:=#/.*()&%!$ @+-]+$/", $string);`

Comment: I also recommend using this $string = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $string);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you don't need to escape most of the metacharacters.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9^_[\]',?;:=#\/.*()&%!$ @+-]+$/
```

- `]` is escaped to prevent it from closing the character class
- `/` needs to be escaped because we're using it as regex delimiter
- `-` doesn't need to be escaped because it's the last character in the class
- `^` doesn't need to be escaped because it's not the first character in the class

Or, if you want a shorter expression, the following regex covers the same range:

```
/^[ !#-;=?-[\]^_a-z]+$/
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: This method also works but there is a much easier and cleaner way. Take a look at me answer bellow

Comment: I prefer to know and explain why each metacharacter needs or doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of worrying about escaping manually use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

The code would then be 
`preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9".preg_quote("^_[]',?;:=#/.*()&%!$ @+-", "/")."]+$/", $string);`

Comment: `preg_quote` is for escaping literal strings, not characters inside a character class. E.g. in this case, it returns `A\-Za\-z0\-9\^_\[\]',\?;\:\=#\/\.\*\(\)&%\!\$ @\+\-`, which is wrong

Comment: I've given this an upvote because it's a good suggestion generally. However regex escaping within a character range (ie within square brackets) has different quoting rules, so preg_quote probably won't be quite right in this context.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it, upvoted. It will escape more characters than what's needed, but this is safe as long as you don't pass character ranges to `preg_quote`.

Comment: If you want to make it even more cleaner then you could define your regex in two variables: one for range and one for other matches and then escape only the matches variable. This is not necessary if you're only using that regex one time

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape most of the chars in your string as they have special meaning in regular expressions

(of course you were right not to escape the leading `^` and the trailing `$` as they indicate that no other character can be in the line):

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\\^_\\[\\]',\\?;:=#/\\.\\*\\(\\)\\&\\%!\\$ @\\+\\-]+$/", $string);
```

For the record a list of the BECS allowed chars vs regular expression chars:

```
Type                        Description
Numeric                     0 to 9
Alphabetic                  Uppercase A to Z and Lowercase a to z
+                           Plus sign: means 1 or more
-                           Minus sign or hyphen: used for char range
$                           Dollar sign: end of line
(                           Left Parenthesis: starts a group
)                           Right Parenthesis: ends a group
*                           Asterik: 0 or more
.                           Period or decimal point: any char (not in a range, would work)
?                           Question mark: 0 or 1
[                           Left square bracket: starts a range
]                           Right square bracket: ends a range
^                           Circumflex: not/line start
```

Comment: Its not working. `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' on line number 5`

Comment: added more backslashes. Seeing other answers, they seem more appriopriate, though.

Comment: Still, you can't have an odd number of backslashes. Also, I'm not a big fan of the "If you don't know the rules, escape everything"...

Comment: I'm editing the answer. Still for the triple backslash before $ I followed this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716443/how-to-escape-dollar-sign-in-a-string-using-perl-regex

Comment: Your link is for a perl program, not a PHP one. Running your code, I get a `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in prog.php on line 4` because the `/` is not escaped. Also, it would have been a lot easier to use `"/^[\w^[\\]',?;:=#\\/.*()&%!$ @+-]+$/"`